# PostGIS use ST_AsBinary by default

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Is there a way to use `ST_AsBinary` by default on every `geometry` (PostGIS type) retrieved from `Postgres`?

Comment: I don't think you're likely to find a system-wide solution. Maybe instead you could make views over your tables with geometry columns, and use ST_AsBinary in the views?

Comment: Any luck with this issue?

Comment: @JimJones I haven't found any solution so far. I am just manually using this function on every retrieval.